Circumferential stress in a toroidal shell
Consider the following formula for circumferential stress (σ2) in a toroidal shell (taken from Roark's Formulae for Stress and Strain):

It seems that it has been derived by using simple force balance as follows :
P x pi x  b^2 = σ2 x 2 x pi x b x t
My question is: How can we assume that the circumferential stress will remain same throughout the periphery? Is it not possible that σ2 varies at different points?

Assumption of constant circumferential stress is correct for $a \gg b$, because the toroid looks like a slightly bend pipe. But for many practical cases, it is not constant, although it is quite a good approximation.
Here is a comparison for example with following parameters:

$P = 5 \text{ MPa}$
$a = 250\text{ mm}$
$b = 50\text{ mm}$
$t\in [10, 4, 1]\text{ mm}$

"MKP" in the figure means FEM and $N$ values are internal forces on unit length of the shell; $N_\varphi = \sigma_2\cdot t$ and $N_\vartheta = \sigma_1\cdot t$. The analytic solution is based on the assumption in question, i.e. that the circumferential stress is constant and then you just use Laplace equation for internal forces and curvatures $\frac{N_\vartheta}{r_\vartheta}+\frac{N_\varphi}{r_\varphi} = P$, where $r_\vartheta = b$ and $r_\varphi$ is variable.

From the practical standpoint, the extreme stresses will be the tangential ones anyway and these are quite accurate even with this "bad" assumption. Formulas for pressure piping elbow thicknesses are based on this simple derivation. There are 2 extreme tangential stress values, the greatest is closest to the axis (denoted in Roark's as $\left(\sigma_1\right)_{\max}$) and the lowest is at the farthest point from the axis. That is especially beneficial for elbows created by bending a straight pipe, as the resulting thickness increases closer to the bending axis and decreases farther from it.

Thank you so much...your explanation is very helpful

@Johnsmith You can "upvote" or "accept" the answer if you find it helpful (more information here).
